# I got this error when execute my app..error taken from logcat

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite

This is my error from logcat

```
11-30 16:03:56.926: E/SQLiteLog(910): (1) near "(": syntax error
11-30 16:03:56.926: D/AndroidRuntime(910): Shutting down VM
11-30 16:03:56.956: W/dalvikvm(910): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
11-30 16:03:57.106: E/AndroidRuntime(910): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-30 16:03:57.106: E/AndroidRuntime(910): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.databasepractice/com.example.databasepractice.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "(": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE  (id integer primary key autoincrement,username text not null,password text not null)
11-30 16:03:57.106: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
11-30 16:03:57.106: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
11-30 16:03:57.106: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
11-30 16:03:57.106: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
11-30 16:03:57.106: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-30 16:03:57.106: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-30 16:03:57.106: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
11-30 16:03:57.106: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-30 16:03:57.106: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-30 16:03:57.106: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
11-30 16:03:57.106: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-30 16:03:57.106: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-30 16:03:57.106: E/AndroidRuntime(910): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "(": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE  (id integer primary key autoincrement,username text not null,password text not null)
11-30 16:03:57.106: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
11-30 16:03:57.106: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
11-30 16:03:57.106: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
11-30 16:03:57.106: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
11-30 16:03:57.106: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
11-30 16:03:57.106: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
11-30 16:03:57.106: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1672)
11-30 16:03:57.106: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1603)
11-30 16:03:57.106: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at com.example.databasepractice.DBHelper.onCreate(DBHelper.java:20)
11-30 16:03:57.106: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
11-30 16:03:57.106: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
11-30 16:03:57.106: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at com.example.databasepractice.DBAdapter.open(DBAdapter.java:28)
11-30 16:03:57.106: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at com.example.databasepractice.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)
11-30 16:03:57.106: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
11-30 16:03:57.106: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
11-30 16:03:57.106: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
11-30 16:03:57.106: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  ... 11 more
11-30 16:04:08.786: I/Process(910): Sending signal. PID: 910 SIG: 9
```

---

```
package com.example.databasepractice;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper  {
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ibwcdb";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE  (id integer primary key autoincrement,username text not null,password text not null)";

public DBHelper(Context context) {
super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int arg1, int arg2) {
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS members");
onCreate(db);

}

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a table name in your `DATABASE_CREATE` String:

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE your_table_name (id integer primary key autoincrement, username text not null, password text not null)";
```